# Why MongoDb Gets Slower?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, server, mern

so im currently working on a mern stack app (https://tearex05.github.io/rexshop-frontend) and the server is good and fast at the beggining but when i upload like 5 images to my free mongodb server it takes too long for my backend to get the items from the mongodb and sometimes it doesnt even get the item.(i use react-base-file64 to convert the images to base64 and then send a post request to backend)

i actually have another collection in the same cluster for the users but it works faster and better than the collection which i have my items in

so my question is: is there a way to make the server faster or are there some servers that i can use instead of mongodb with the mern stack? tnx

Comment: The size of the images, the number of concurrent connections, the network latency, and other factors can affect the speed of image uploads. Available resources on the free tier plan could be a factor?

However, you can try to optimize your database and network for better performance, for example by using a caching layer, compressing the images, indexing your collections etc.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on the documents you're storing in MongoDB and how exactly you're storing images?

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB is designed for handling structured data and so on is not the most officient solution for storing large binary files such as images as you're doing. You could try other solutions like Google Cloud Cold Storage if you want to improve server performance.